# WAMP is not running

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I had installed WAMP in E: drive. I re-installed fresh copy of windows. Since then, WAMP only comes in red shade , not coming in green mode. Please help what should I do?

Comment: It is not coming in running mode. I have lots of important databases in phpadmin of wamp. Please help otherwise i am gonna lose them all. :(

Comment: type `E:\WAMP\apache\bin\httpd.exe` in command prompt and let us know the output. Or give us the apache log file through pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

port 80 might be used by other services. test that using apache>services>test port 80. and disable that service.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows is re-install or upgraded in-place, sometimes both the Apache and MySQL services are cleared out and the PATH environmental variable is reset.

1. Update the Path with the "bin" folders of Apache and MySQL.
2. Re-install the services...

If you are using WampDeveloper (I don't know which WAMP you are using), to install the services again it's (from the command line running as administrator):

Install Services:

```
httpd -k install -f "C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Apache\httpd.conf" -DSSL
mysqld --install Mysql --defaults-file="C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Mysql\my.ini"
```

The generic forms are:

```
Apache22\bin\httpd -k install
mysql5\bin\mysqld --install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Skpey exit and restart all service.
Tip:
on skype menu --> Tools --> Options --> advanced --> connection
Disable "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections"